# What frameworks to build an offline webapp

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, offline-mode

What framework supports building webapp that work offline ?

I believe that most of the webapp should be coded in javascript to be usable offline, and that data should be synchronized when the webapp connects online.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the most popular:

- [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) (from Google)
- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [appjs](http://appjs.org/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs)

That are frameworks that will give you the basic code structure/organization for your application, based on MVC pattern mostly. Some of them has already UI widgets library (like ExtJS) but for the rest you may want to use a UI library on top of them that give you sweets widgets to be used from jQuery or similar, like:

- [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) and [jquery-mobile](http://jquerymobile.com)
- [Kendoui](http://www.kendoui.com)